Fixing template invocation condition in Azure DevOps pipeline
I'm having trouble with a stage in our Azure DevOps project that's being executed when we need it not to be. It might be a canRun parameter problem.
We have a YAML template pipeline that deploys the image from a previous build to Kubernetes in one of our environments. That template is invoked multiple times from another YAML pipeline, once for each of the environments in turn, conditionally: builds from the main branch are deployed to Development and QC, while builds from any release/* branch are deployed to Test, then Production, then Contingency, which is supposed to mirror Production. The YAML for the release series is as follows:
- template: deploy-pipeline-job-template.yml
  parameters:
    canRun: and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), startsWith(variables['resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'))
    stageName: Test
    variableGroup: myproj-web-variables-test
    buildPipelineId: ${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}
    devOpsEnvironment: myproj-test
    kubernetesServiceConnection: myproj-dev-kubeconfig
- template: deploy-pipeline-job-template.yml
  parameters:
    canRun: and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), startsWith(variables['resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'))
    stageName: Production
    variableGroup: myproj-web-variables-prod
    buildPipelineId: ${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}
    devOpsEnvironment: myproj-prod
    kubernetesServiceConnection: myproj-prod-kubeconfig
- template: deploy-pipeline-job-template.yml
  parameters:
    canRun: and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), startsWith(variables['resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'))
    stageName: Contingency
    variableGroup: myproj-web-variables-cont
    buildPipelineId: ${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}
    devOpsEnvironment: myproj-cont
    kubernetesServiceConnection: myproj-cont-kubeconfig

QC, Test, and Production are configured to require approval. After an approver has approved a release build for deployment to Test and receives a prompt to approve deployment to Production, the following should happen:

If an approver approves the build for Production, it should be deployed to both Production and Contingency.
If no approver ever approves the build for Production, it should never be deployed to either Production or Contingency.

The first of these is happening: When the Production approval is submitted, the Production stage runs and is immediately followed by the Contingency stage.
The problem is in the second case. DevOps imposes a 30-day limit on the waiting period for approvals. What's actually happening is that when the waiting period expires, the build, while not being deployed to Production, is being deployed to Contingency, so that Contingency no longer mirrors Production and is instead hosting a version that hasn't been approved and may never be approved.
Is there a way to prevent the deployment to Contingency in this case? Is there something I can add to the canRun parameter in the template invocation to achieve this? There doesn't seem to be a skipped() to go along with failed() and canceled(). In the worse case, we could add an approval requirement for Contingency and then the approvers would just have to remember that every time they deploy to Production, they have to jump on the incoming prompt, a few seconds later, to approve Contingency as well, but I'd prefer not to add the extra approval step.
UPDATE: I found a post from someone with the reverse problem, where the later stage was being skipped (they were using succeeded()) and they didn't want it to be (someone advised them to use not(or(failed(), succeeded())), corresponding to the reply from Miao Tian-MSFT, below. Azure multistage pipelines: conditionally skip one stage but not the next

Hi @Green, I noticed that you edited the post with that reverse problem. So, using succeeded() instead of not(or(failed(), canceled())) can solve the issue, right? Thanks for your update.

I was going to set up a test scenario but got side-tracked. That is how it should work, I'll report back how it goes.

Hi @Green, thanks for your update and looking forward to hearing your test result.

According to your description, your canrun parameter should be the condition of a stage.
You can change Contingency stage as the following to ensure that the Contingency stage only runs after the Production stage is succeeded.
- template: deploy-pipeline-job-template.yml
  parameters:
    canRun: and(succeeded(),  startsWith(variables['resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'))
    stageName: Contingency
    variableGroup: myproj-web-variables-cont
    buildPipelineId: ${{ parameters.buildPipelineId }}
    devOpsEnvironment: myproj-cont
    kubernetesServiceConnection: myproj-cont-kubeconfig

My test yaml:
stages:
  - stage: test
    jobs:
    - job: 
      steps:
      - bash: echo "hello"
  - stage: Production
    jobs:
    - deployment: DeployWeb
      displayName: deploy Web App
      pool:
        vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
      environment: 
        name: 'smarthotel-dev'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - script: echo Hello world
  - stage: Contingency
    condition: and(succeeded(),  startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
    jobs:
    - job: 
      steps:
      - bash: echo "hello Contingency"

My test result


If you need to test the issue, and don't want to wait 30 days, you can set a short timeout time to the approval.  Just for test if this works.
